# tiles/nodes within a certain range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently creating a game in which actors move on a two dimensional grid. I want to display the all the tiles within a a certain actors movement range. Each tile has a reference to its neighbours(no diagonal movement allowed) and the amount of movement points it costs to move to that tile. I am trying to figure out a cheap algorithm to find all tiles within the actors range. I could run a dijkstra algorithm without a target but that seems way overkill ):

Comment: Well, if the tiles are actual game objects, and you are working on the main thread, do a spherecast, usually way more efficient than implementing a pathfinding algorithm. If you want to go with pathfinding, use a simple A* algorithm.

Comment: I already have a a* pathfinding algorithm implemented. For pathfinding purposes I am using nodes that aren't actual game objects, their coordinates just represent a gameobject in the scene. What I am looking for is a quick way to get ALL the tiles the actor can move to without having to use the a* pathfinding algorithm on every tile

Comment: Are your nodes in an array? Do they have their own positions? If so you could calculate distance between each of nodes and get only those which meet your requirement. I know it's not the fastest, but I don't know how they are set up in your game.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have already solved that problem, for anyone interested, I've basically used an a* star algorithm without a valid target and stored my nodes in an heap. Before I start the a* search I calculate the maximum amount of nodes a unit could theoretically move to and if my list of reachable nodes is equal to that amount I stop searching. Code executes in 0-3ms that way even on large maps, making it perfect to display reachable nodes for multiple units during runtime.